# What am I doing wrong in calculating the mean square error?

Tags: fitting, warning-messages, broken-code

I am trying to compare the results of estimators from least squares and quantile regression from the perspective of the mean square error (MSE).
The steps for performing this Monte Carlo approach are:

1. Set parameters;
2. Generate data (x and y to be more specific, for three different betas). `xnod` and `tau*quantile` will be used later to build true estimator;
3. Run `QuantileRegressionFit` and extract parameters;
4. Run `LinearModelFit` and extract parameters, including errors. These errors are needed to build the quantile for least squares results (just add the quantile of errors to the final equation).
5. Rebuild the true y's at a fixed point (`xnod`) and compare with `yqr` (rebuilt using quantile regression parameters) and with `yls` at the same `xnod`.
6. Compare calculating MSE.

My supervisor believes that my results are wrong because the MSEs are too large, except for the first, $\beta_{low}$.
I have examined this code and fine-tuned it many times.
Can someone please help me by pointing out where are my errors and suggestions to fix them?

```
AppendTo[$Path, FileNameJoin[{"D:", "Wolfram Mathematica"}]];
Needs["QuantileRegression`"]
```

Set n, m and τ

```
n = 1000;
τ = 0.95;
columns = 10000;
m = columns;
```

Generate data

```
SeedRandom[41];
xdata = Table[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], n], columns];
xnod = InverseCDF[NormalDistribution[], τ];
ϵdata = Table[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], n], columns];
τquantile = InverseCDF[NormalDistribution[], τ];
βdata = {1/3, 1, 3};
numβ = Length[βdata];
ydata = Table[xdata βdata[[k]] + ϵdata, {k, numβ}];
data = Table[Transpose[{ydata[[q, k]], xdata[[k]]}], {q, numβ}, {k, columns}];
```

Quantile Regression

```
funcs = {1, x};
qrFuncs = Table[QuantileRegressionFit[#, funcs, x, {τ}] & /@ data[[q]], {q, numβ}];
qrFuncsFlat = Flatten[qrFuncs];
parametersQRflat = 
  MapThread[Join, 
    {Map[Cases[#, _?NumberQ] &, qrFuncsFlat] /. {} -> {0}, 
     Outer[Coefficient, qrFuncsFlat, DeleteCases[funcs, _?NumberQ]]}];
parametersQR = Partition[parametersQRflat, columns];
```

Run Least Squares

```
lsFunc = Table[LinearModelFit[#, x, x] & /@ data[[q]], {q, numβ}];
parametersLs = Table[lsFunc[[q, j]]["BestFitParameters"], {q, numβ}, {j, columns}];
residualsLs = Table[lsFunc[[q, j]]["FitResiduals"], {q, numβ}, {j, columns}];
```

Estimated quantiles

```
qϵhat = Table[Quantile[#, τ] & /@ residualsLs[[q]], {q, numβ}];
```

Quantile regression estimator, least squares estimator and true estimator

```
yqr = 
  Table[
    parametersQR[[q, k, 1]] + parametersQR[[q, k, 2]] xnod, 
    {q, numβ}, {k, columns}];
yls = 
   Table[
     qϵhat[[q, k]] + parametersLs[[q, k, 2]] xnod + parametersLs[[q, k, 1]], 
     {q, numβ}, {k, columns}];
yactual = τquantile + xnod βdata;
```

MSE

```
mseQR = Table[Total[(yqr[[q]] - yactual[[q]])^2]/m, {q, numβ}];
mseLS = Table[Total[(yls[[q]] - yactual[[q]])^2]/m, {q, numβ}];
```

Bias^2

```
biasQR = Table[(Total[yqr[[q]] - yactual[[q]]]/m)^2, {q, numβ}];
biasLS = Table[(Total[yls[[q]] - yactual[[q]]]/m)^2, {q, numβ}];
```

Variance

```
varQR = mseQR - biasQR;
varLS = mseLS - biasLS;
```

Conjecture and table of results

[image: TableResults]

10000 columns took my computer about 6 - 7 hours to run.
I have included the issues that occurred with `QuantileRegressionFit` during calculation:

```
qrFuncs = Table[QuantileRegressionFit[#, funcs, x, {τ}] & /@ data[[q]], {q, numβ}];
```

> LinearProgramming::lpipcv: Warning: the interior point algorithm cannot converge to the tolerance of 1.4901161193847656`*^-8. The best residual achieved is 0.00004395507383878355`, and the solution at that residual has been returned. Setting the option Method -> RevisedSimplex should give a more definite answer, though large problems may take longer computing time.
>
> LinearProgramming::lpipcv: Warning: the interior point algorithm cannot converge to the tolerance of 1.4901161193847656`*^-8. The best residual achieved is 6.671193676426196`*^-7, and the solution at that residual has been returned. Setting the option Method -> RevisedSimplex should give a more definite answer, though large problems may take longer computing time.
>
> LinearProgramming::lpipcv: Warning: the interior point algorithm cannot converge to the tolerance of 1.4901161193847656`*^-8. The best residual achieved is 2.2673711534277855`*^-6, and the solution at that residual has been returned. Setting the option Method -> RevisedSimplex should give a more definite answer, though large problems may take longer computing time.

Comment: I figured it out!! When Transposing the data to prepare them for the regression functions, I switched the order. X must come first!! Cheers

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP found a mistake and the topic is too specific to help future visitors.